# CKEditor - kcfinder browse server does not work

Tags: browser, ckeditor, kcfinder

First of all I apologize for my poor english.

I am using CKEditor on my website and I've integrated kcfind.

Click the browse button was added to the server.

But when I click the button, this screen is displayed.

[image: image of the problem]

Blank pop-up windows and buttons do not work.

Answer (score 0):

chek out if it is ok the url where you set the file

```
file_browser_callback: function(field, url, type, win) {
        tinyMCE.activeEditor.windowManager.open({

            file: 'your url'
    (check the correct url)
```

if it matches the url you have in your browser, try to change it to instead of 127.0.0.1 => use localhost

Answer (score 0):

1. Possibly you have a typing error, 127.0.01 instead of 127.0.0.1
2. Kcfinder works with default port (80) only, I think. I tried at 8080 and it didn't work. Exactly same config worked well on a different server at 80.